# Using ffprobe in Android

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I'm using Ffmpeg via this [link](http://hiteshsondhi88.github.io/ffmpeg-android-java/) and works fine, but it failures when I try to use "ffprobe" commands to get video info. For example, currently I'm using these lines of codes :

```
ffmpeg.execute("ffprobe -v quiet -print_format json -show_format -show_streams some.mp4",
 new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() { ... });
```

Above code lines don't work and **ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler**'s **onFailure** method get called. But reason **message** of **onFailure** is empty. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Any idea?

Comment: ffmpeg for Android does not include `ffprpbe`

Comment: thanks for the answer, I'll try another way to get info from video file.

Comment: Any updates, how ffprobe can be used within android?

Answer (score 1):

You can use FFprobe with this library: [FFmpeg-Android](https://github.com/bravobit/FFmpeg-Android)

```
FFprobe ffprobe = FFprobe.getInstance(context);
try {
  // to execute "ffprobe -version" command you just need to pass "-version"
  ffprobe.execute(cmd, new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onStart() {}

    @Override
    public void onProgress(String message) {}

    @Override
    public void onFailure(String message) {}

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(String message) {}

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {}

  });
} catch (FFprobeCommandAlreadyRunningException e) {
  // Handle if FFprobe is already running
}
```